# Radio buttons in jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a product X that I would like to be able to customize in other words to change the colors of certain portion of the product X once the radio button that has certain color value is selected. To do this was quite simple. However, customization of this product should be limited by the color combinations and that is where the problem comes. I need to be able to select a first color from first jquery tab. Than select the second color from the second tab. Than based on those two selections, I should only be prompted with those two color options for all other jquery tabs which I have several. Can you visualize what I am trying to say here?

Each color is represented with the radio button that has a color value assigned to it.
To further explain my problem lets select color blue out of bunch in tab 1. Than lets select color red from tab 2. The tab 3 and all remaining tabs should only provide radio buttons for blue and red. The other options should be grayed out or simply not offered.

The link to the website is: http://flyingcowproduction.com/pps/

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't expect people to follow links to random sites. Always include all the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: What is the actual problem with the code on that page? What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery .change() to check which color has been selected and hide or disable unvalid combination in the remaining tabs.